# Implement oauth in AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to create a simple service using AWS API gateway and Lambda.

I want to manage small amount of user/password pairs such that they can login in to get an access token to proceed with future API calls.

I am not sure if I have chosen the right tools for this, but I am wondering if there is any existing package or model that I can use to implement this functionality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A document titled "[Amazon API Gateway + AWS Lambda + OAuth](https://www.authlete.com/documents/apigateway_lambda_oauth)" describes what you need to do to protect a Web API implemented using [Amazon API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/) + [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) with an [OAuth 2.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) access token. The introspection API (= an API to get information about an access token) used in the document is [Authlete](https://www.authlete.com/)'s one, but you can replace it with another different one you like. For example, if you use an authorization server implementation that supports [RFC 7662](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7662) (OAuth 2.0 Token Introspection), you can use the introspection API defined in the specification.

---

Updated on 2016-Apr-6

On Feb 11, 2016, a blog entry of [AWS Compute Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/jp/blogs/compute/), "[Introducing custom authorizers in Amazon API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/jp/blogs/compute/introducing-custom-authorizers-in-amazon-api-gateway)", announced that **Custom Authorizer** had been introduced into Amazon API Gateway. Thanks to this mechanism, an API built on Amazon API Gateway can delegate validation of a Bearer token (such as an OAuth or SAML token) presented by a client application to an external authorizer.

How to protect APIs built on Amazon API Gateway by OAuth access tokens utilizing the new mechanism, Custom Authorier, is described in "[Amazon APi Gateway Custom Authorizer + OAuth](https://www.authlete.com/documents/article/custom_authorizer)".

Comment: @Metallikanz Thank you. The server was restarted and Authlete site is now available.

Comment: Thanks... That was pretty quick!

Comment: Really sorry. We restarted the web server and will surely plan to change the hosting service. Please send a message to Twitter authlete next time you encounter a trouble again.